# Hide content in listbox item depending on a binding property in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, listbox, visibility

I have xaml that lookes like this

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="contentPanel" >
            Content goes here...
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The listbox binds to an object with a bool property called ShowContent.
How do I get silverlight to hide the contentPanel if the object with ShowContent is false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a BoolToVisibility IValueConveter and use it to bind to the Visibility property of your contentPanel

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding YourBoolProperty, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityResourceRef ..../>
```

You can find a BoolToVisibility pretty easy anywhere.

Check IValueConveter if you are new to that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: There is a BooleanToVisibilityConverter which is part of the framework.

Comment: I have tried that and it doen't work. It will probably work in wpf but not in silverlight.

Comment: :) It should work in Silverlight - Here is a quick search result http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting the ListBoxItem visibility at the ListBoxItem level or you will end up with tiny empty listbox items due to the default padding and border values e.g.

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBox.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding MyItem.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
          </Style>
     </ListBox.Resources>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding MyItemName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This hides the entire ListBoxItem not just the contents of it.